Average number of prime divisors of $n$-digit numbers
While messing around with some big numbers, I came up with a question:
Given a natural number $n$, what is the average number of prime divisors of all $n$-digit numbers?
This seemed to be a pretty simple thing to find, so I found a way to express it in Desmos. Essentially I expressed the aforementioned average as
$$A(n)=\frac{1}{9\cdot10^{n-1}}\sum_{k=10^{n-1}}^{10^n-1}\theta(k),\qquad n>1$$
where $\theta(k)$ gives the number of prime divisors (not counting multiplicity) of $k$. The $9\cdot 10^{n-1}$ is easily seen to be the number of $n$-digit numbers. Also easily seen is that $10^{n-1}$ is the smallest $n$-digit number and $10^n-1$ is the largest.
The process for calculating $A(1)$ is the easiest. There are clearly $10$ numbers with only one digit, so $$A(1)=\frac1{10}(0+0+1+1+1+1+2+1+1)=\frac{9}{10}.$$
Then according to Desmos,
$$A(2)=\frac{16}{9}=1.\bar7$$
$$A(3)=\frac{391}{180}=2.17\bar2$$
Unfortunately, the way I computed $\theta(n)$ was such that the computation of $A(4)$ is too much for Desmos to handle. This makes sense though, as I computed $\theta(n)$ as
$$\theta(n)=\sum_{l=1}^{n}\left\{\left\lfloor\exp\left(l-1-\lfloor 1/l\rfloor -\sum_{k=1}^{l-1}\gcd(l,k)\right)\right\rfloor\cdot\left\lfloor\exp\left(l\lfloor n/l\rfloor-n\right)\right\rfloor\right\},$$
which is, understandably, extremely computationally expensive. I am sure if there was a simpler, more efficient way to compute $\theta(n)$, I would be able to compute $A(4)$ (and likely more).
So I have the following questions: Is there any simpler way to compute $\theta(n)$? What are the values of $A(n)$ for $n\ge4$? Can we get a lower/upper bound on $A(n)$? Has anyone investigated $A(n)$ before?
Thank you!

https://math.dartmouth.edu/~stevefan/papers/The%20Erdos-Kac%20Theorem.pdf

https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Hardy-Ramanujan_theorem

The function that you call $\theta$ is usually denoted $\omega$, the prime omega function.  There are two such functions, the lower-case one counts prime divisors without multiplicity.  (The upper case one counts with multiplicity.)
The current state of the art for computing $\omega$ for a particular integer is: factor the integer and count prime divisors.  Common prime factorization implementations in Desmos seem to use a list of primes and test against them.  Examples: 1, 2.  Although there are alternatives: 3.
I might run a pre-pass similar to the sieve of Eratosthenes on your list of same-length integers to mark (and divide out) factors of 2, 3, 5, and 7.  Then check each later one to see if its quotient is already on the list.  (Since your intervals have a factor of $10$ between the top and the bottom, the upper half-ish gives quotients in the lower half, the upper two-thirds-ish in the lower third, and so on.)
The Hardy-Ramanujan theorem states that for any $\varepsilon > 0$, almost all integers, $n \in \Bbb{Z}$,
$$ | \omega(n) - \ln \ln n | < \varepsilon \ln \ln n  \text{.}  $$
The Erdős-Kac theorem strengthens this.  The precise statement is a bit cumbersome, but for use here a summarized statement is $\omega(n)$ is normally distributed with mean $\ln \ln n$ and variance $\ln \ln n$.  (Clearly we should avoid evaluating these with $n = 1$.)  This suggests computing
\begin{align*}
B(1) &= \frac{1}{8} \sum_{j=2}^9 \ln \ln j  \\
B(k) &= \frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \sum_{j=10^{k-1}}^{10^k-1} \ln \ln j  \text{,}  
\end{align*}
although we should expect the agreement to be poor for small numbers and improve as we study larger ranges.
If one doesn't have time for the detailed sum, one can approximate with an integral.
\begin{align*}
B_{\text{int}}(1) &= \frac{1}{8} \int_2^9 \; \ln \ln j \,\mathrm{d}j \\
B_{\text{int}}(k) &= \frac{1}{9 \cdot 10^{k-1}} \int_{10^{k-1}}^{10^k-1} \; \ln \ln j \,\mathrm{d}j
\end{align*}
If one has access to a library that can evaluate the logarithmic integral, one can antidifferentiate and use
$$  \int \ln \ln j \,\mathrm{d}j = j \ln ( \ln j ) - \mathrm{li}(j)  $$
to evaluate "directly".  (The logarithmic integral grows like $O(x/\ln x)$, so roughly at the rate of the prime counting function.)  Values of $B_{\text{int}}$ also appear in the table below.  They clearly approach $B$ better than $B$ approaches the correct value.
We can also use mathematical software to compute the average of the prime omega function.  In Mathematica, for instance, the $\omega$ function is PrimeNu.  (PrimeOmega is the upper-case prime omega function that counts prime divisors with multiplicity.)  So we can compute
CC[k_] := 1/(9 * 10^(k-1)) Sum[PrimeNu[j],{j,10^(k-1),10^k-1}]

PrimeNu[0] is undefined, so we expect a slightly different result than $A(1)$.
A slightly different cumulative prime omega function question was studied on Math Overflow.  Most solutions used summation by parts to reduce to $\sum_{n=1}^N \omega(n)$.  The resulting error term wasn't awesome, so the current state of the art doesn't give a precision shortcut for the average value of $\omega$ on intervals.
Computing with those, we find
\begin{align*}
k&  &  B&(k)          &  B_{\text{int}}&(k)  &  \texttt{CC}&\texttt{[k]} &  \\
1&  & 0&.41228{\dots} &  0&.39271{\dots}    &  1&                \\
2&  & 1&.2240{\dots}  &  1&.32101{\dots}    &  1&.77777{\dots}   \\
3&  & 1&.8136{\dots}  &  1&.81167{\dots}    &  2&.172222{\dots}  \\
4&  & 2&.13355{\dots} &  2&.13331{\dots}    &  2&.463777{\dots}  \\
5&  & 2&.37511{\dots} &  2&.37508{\dots}    &  2&.69             \\
6&  & 2&.56938{\dots} &  2&.56938{\dots}    &  2&.874786{\dots}  \\
7&  & 2&.73192{\dots} &  2&.73192{\dots}    &  3&.030734{\dots}  \\
8&  & 2&.87167{\dots} &  2&.87167{\dots}    &  3&.165632{\dots}  \\
\end{align*}
Looks like the estimates $B$ and $B_{\text{int}}$ start a little low and don't differ by much for more than 6 digit numbers.  No idea if they ever exceed CC (dancing around above and below... for larger and larger decades of integers).

Not an answer, but I did compute $A(n)$ for $n=4,5,6,7,8$:



$n$
$A(n)$




$1$
$\frac{   9         }{  10      } \approx 0.9               $


$2$
$\frac{   160       }{  90      } \approx 1.7777777777778   $


$3$
$\frac{   1955      }{  900     } \approx 2.1722222222222   $


$4$
$\frac{   22174     }{  9000    } \approx 2.4637777777778   $


$5$
$\frac{   242100    }{  90000   } \approx 2.69              $


$6$
$\frac{   2587308   }{  900000  } \approx 2.8747866666667   $


$7$
$\frac{   27276609  }{  9000000 } \approx 3.0307343333333   $


$8$
$\frac{   284906964  }{  90000000 } \approx 3.1656329333333   $




Let $~M~$ be the largest positive integer such that a complete list of primes from $~1~$ thru $~10^M~$ is available.  Assume that there are $~r~$ such primes, and index the primes in ascending order as $~p_1, ~p_2, ~\cdots, ~p_r.$
For example $~p_1 = 2, ~p_2 = 3.$
For $~x \in \Bbb{R}, ~$ let $~\lfloor x\rfloor~$ denote the largest integer $~\leq x~$ (i.e. the floor function).
For any $~n \in \Bbb{Z^+},~$ such that $~n \leq M,~$ your function
$$\theta(k) ~: ~10^{n-1} \leq k < 10^n $$
can be alternatively computed as
$$\sum_{k = 1}^r \left\{ ~\left\lfloor ~\frac{10^n - 1}{p_k} ~\right\rfloor - \left\lfloor ~\frac{10^{n-1} - 1}{p_k} ~\right\rfloor ~\right\}.$$
Within the above summation, you are (in effect) computing the number of multiples of the prime $~p_k~$ that are in range.  Naturally, you would halt the summation whenever a prime $~p_k \geq 10^n~$ is encountered.
Personally, I don't know if the constraint in this answer's first paragraph makes this approach impractical for you.
Also, although I suspect that the suggested computation of $~\theta(k)~$ is computationally inexpensive, assuming that the list of primes has been read into an array, I have never personally tested this approach.

$\underline{\text{Addendum}}$
This Addendum is off-topic re math analysis, but discusses a possible approach to optimize the code.
Java features integer division, where (for example)
$$7 \div 2 = 3.$$
I presume that such programming languages
as C or Python offer a similar facility.
While I suspect that integer division is computationally less expensive than a canned floor function (if one exists), I have never tested that.
